# Error using Algebraic Constraint in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to implement an equation

> c= a*w*(sinwt + b*sin(2*w*t))

where w is varying and a,b and c are all constants.

I have done it using Agebraic Constraint block but I am getting an error

> Trouble solving algebraic loop containing 'trial1/Algebraic Constraint1/Initial Guess' at time >0. Stopping simulation. There may be a singularity in the solution. If the model is correct, >try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error >tolerances)

Pl help as in what might be wrong. Or suggest what are the other ways of solving the equation and finding a graph of w vs t(using scope).

Comment: That equation isn't guaranteed to have a solution.  For instance at t=0, if c is not zero then there is no solution.  Or at any point if w*t is a multiple of pi then there is no solution unless c=0.

Comment: Yes,your observation is valid but it would have a solution at some points.How to exactly find the the solution at those points?

Comment: The optimization algorithm underlying the Algebraic Constraint block requires that a solution exists at every time step.  You need to either rethink what you're modelling, or rewrite it to call an external optimization function (e.g. a MATLAB optimization function, through a Function Block or an S-Function) that returns a NaN or other similar value when a solution cannot otherwise be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing equation in this manner.
I have taken a=1,b=1,c=1 & w=1

```
c= @(t) (a*w*(sin(t) + b*sin(2*w*t)));
t = linspace (-pi,pi,1000);
figure
plot (t,c(t))
```

Comment: OP is asking using Simulik's scope block, probably he's interested in Simulation